# Is it possible to take a photo of an object and determine that object's colour using openCV?

Tags: colors, opencv, comparison, photo, rgb

My problem is this.
Could I take the photo of the object and compare the dominant color in it to an image of a color wheel and determine where it stands on that wheel? Returning and saving the information of what color it is so it can be used in a further function? Or would I have to make a table of RGB intervals that determinate colors and compare to that instead?

Comment: Sure, both solutions could be implemented, but have you taken the time to analyze the complexity of the project? Do you have some proficiency on OpenCV?

Comment: Anyway, you might want to take a look at histograms: http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/drawing-histograms-in-opencv/

Comment: Above link doesn't work anymore - here's the updated one: http://aishack.in/tutorials/drawing-histograms-in-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

http://www.andol.info/hci/774.htm
http://myopencv.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/detecting-colors-using-rgb-color-space/
http://myopencv.wordpress.com/category/color-detection/